# The Orcutt Package Calculates DW using residuals from the Last Step of OC Procedure

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, economics

> This began as a question, but after reading the reference provided in the answer below, as well as the source code, the solution became clear. In case anyone else finds themselves in this position:

The ***orcutt*** package, version 2.2 uses a special procedure to calculate the DW statistic for its CO models.  The MWE uses the ***orcutt*** package's example to show that its Durbin-Watson statistic is not based on the residuals of the OC estimation.

```
library(orcutt)
data(icecream, package="orcutt")
dw_calc = function(x){sum((x[2:length(x)] - x[1:(length(x)-1)]) ^ 2) / sum(x ^ 2)}    
lm = lm(cons ~ price + income + temp, data=icecream)
e = lm$residuals
dw_calc(e)
# 1.02117   <- Durbin-Watson Statistic

coch = cochrane.orcutt(lm)
e = coch$residuals
dw_calc(e)
# 1.006431  <- Durbin-Watson Statistic

coch
# Durbin-Watson statistic 
# (original):    1.02117 , p-value: 3.024e-04
# (transformed): 1.54884 , p-value: 5.061e-02
```

The ***orcutt*** package reports 1.54884 but the actual DW is 1.006431 for the new residuals. The reported value, 1.54884, comes from the last round of the convergence procedure (see Hildreth-Lu). See below for a thorough explanation:

```
lm = lm(cons ~ price + income + temp, data=icecream)
reg = lm(cons ~ price + income + temp, data=icecream)
convergence = 8
X <- model.matrix(reg) 
Y <- model.response(model.frame(reg)) 
n<-length(Y) 
e<-reg$residuals   
e2<-e[-1] 
e3<-e[-n] 
regP<-lm(e2~e3-1) 
rho<-summary(regP)$coeff[1] 
rho2<-c(rho) 
XB<-X[-1,]-rho*X[-n,] 
YB<-Y[-1]-rho*Y[-n] 
regCO<-lm(YB~XB-1) 
ypCO<-regCO$coeff[1]+as.matrix(X[,-1])%*%regCO$coeff[-1]   
e1<-ypCO-Y 
e2<-e1[-1] 
e3<-e1[-n] 
regP<-lm(e2~e3-1)  
rho<-summary(regP)$coeff[1] 
rho2[2]<-rho 
i<-2 
while (round(rho2[i-1],convergence)!=round(rho2[i],convergence)){ 
  XB<-X[-1,]-rho*X[-n,] 
  YB<-Y[-1]-rho*Y[-n] 
  regCO<-lm(YB~XB-1) 
  ypCO<-regCO$coeff[1]+as.matrix(X[,-1])%*%regCO$coeff[-1]   
  e1<-ypCO-Y 
  e2<-e1[-1] 
  e3<-e1[-n] 
  regP<-lm(e2~e3-1) 
  rho<-summary(regP)$coeff[1]   
  i<-i+1 
  rho2[i]<-rho 
} 

regCO$number.interaction<-i-1 
regCO$rho <- rho2[i-1]

regCO$DW <- c(lmtest::dwtest(reg)$statistic, lmtest::dwtest(reg)$p.value,
              lmtest::dwtest(regCO)$statistic, lmtest::dwtest(regCO)$p.value)

dw_calc(regCO$residuals)

regF<-lm(YB ~ 1)
tF <- anova(regCO,regF)

regCO$Fs <- c(tF$F[2],tF$`Pr(>F)`[2])

# fitted.value
regCO$fitted.values <- model.matrix(reg) %*% (as.matrix(regCO$coeff))


# coeff
names(regCO$coefficients) <- colnames(X)

# st.err
regCO$std.error <- summary(regCO)$coeff[,2]

# t value
regCO$t.value <- summary(regCO)$coeff[,3]

# p value
regCO$p.value <- summary(regCO)$coeff[,4]       


class(regCO) <- "orcutt"


# formula
regCO$call <- reg$call    

# F statistics and p value
df1 <-  dim(model.frame(reg))[2] - 1
df2 <- length(regCO$residuals) - df1 - 1

RSS <- sum((regCO$residuals)^2)  
TSS <- sum((regCO$model[1] - mean(regCO$model[,1]))^2)

regCO$rse <- sqrt(RSS/df2)
regCO$r.squared <- 1 - (RSS/TSS)
regCO$adj.r.squared <-  1 - ((RSS/df2)/(TSS/(df1 + df2)))

regCO$gdl <- c(df1, df2)

# 
regCO$rank <- df1
regCO$df.residual <- df2    
regCO$assign <- regCO$assign[-(df1+1)]    

regCO$residuals <- Y - regCO$fitted.values
regCO
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this area well, but it seems much more likely that there are multiple definitions/estimation methods for this statistic. Going back to the book cited in `?orcutt` (Verbeek M. (2004) *A guide to modern econometrics*, John Wiley & Sons Ltd, ISBN:978-88-08-17054-5), and searching on [Google books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uEFm6pAJZhoC&pg=PA113&dq=verbeek+orcutt&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT5sXJ2OLXAhVK4IMKHRFNDagQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=verbeek%20orcutt&f=false) gives

[image]

The value shown as computed by `orcutt` in your example above agrees with the value given in the book. Earlier in the book (p. 108) it says

> In [the Cochrane-Orcutt procedure], $\rho$ and $\beta$ are recursively estimated until convergence, i.e. having estimated $\beta$ by EGLS (by $\beta^*$), the residuals are recomputed and $\rho$ is estimated again using the residuals from the EGLS step. With this new estimate of $\rho$, EGLS is applied again and one obtains a new estimate of $\beta$ ...

In other words, it seems as though the estimate of $\rho$ that you give above corresponds only to the first step of the Orcutt-Cochrane procedure.